# How to add a context menu on unused column header in TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I'd like to add a right click context menu for a TableView on the unused column space. Is there a way to do this? This is the space between the last used column and the end of the table.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the [table] column header?

Comment: No, the right of the last column header is unused space. That's what I'm referring to.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a [mcve] so that I can copy it and run it on my machine and see what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty area of the `TableView`'s header is called `filler`. CSS selector is:

```css
.table-view > .column-header-background > .filler
```

You can add a `ContextMenu` to this region like this:

```java
ContextMenu fillerContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("Do in filler"));
Region filler = (Region) tableView.lookup(".filler");
filler.setOnContextMenuRequested(event -> {
    fillerContextMenu.show(filler, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
    event.consume();
});
```

**Note:** In order for `lookup(String selector)` to return the acctual node not null, this method should be called after your `TableView` is shown.

Comment: Thanks , it worked but for some reason, the menu pops up way to the left... can you check it? I've updated my question with the example...

Comment: It's a typo. It should be `event.getScreenX()` and ___not___ `event.getSceneX()`

Comment: As @Abra mentioned, it was a typo. I will update my answer now.

Comment: good answer :) With a slight visual glitch (in fx11/win10, didn't test other versions): the font of the menu items is bold. That's different from menu items in a column's contextMenu (which is plain). Reason is that for the latter there's an explicit rule in default styling. So need to add the same styling to filler's contextMenu, something like `.table-view .filler .context-menu {
 -fx-font-weight: null;
}
`